# Download File from remote Ftp Server (file downloaded empty)

Tags: java, ftp, remote-server

I'am traying to download a file from a remote ftp server using Java (`FTPClient`). The file has been downloaded successfully but it's empty and i didnt find a solution for my problem

this is my code

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                 try {

                        ftpClient.connect(ip, port);
                        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                        ftpClient.epsv();
                        ftpClient.mlsd();

                        File downloadFile = new File("contextFolder/test.txt");
                        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
                        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile);

                        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
                        int length;
                        //copy the file content in bytes 
                        while ((length = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) > 0){

                            outputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, length);

                        }

                        Boolean success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

                        outputStream.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        if (success) {
                            System.out.println("File "+remoteFile+" has been downloaded successfully.");
                        }


            }catch(Exception ex){}
```

I need to save the file into the contextFolder with the name test.txt :) Thank You all :)

---

This is the exception that i'm getting

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:483)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:556)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:605)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pasv(FTP.java:956)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:806)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1853)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1844)
    at com.ericsson.etl.module.Activity1.execute(Activity1.java:49)
    at com.ericsson.etl.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequenceProcessor.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the "File XXX has been downloaded" message?  If not, the likely cause is that an exception is being thrown, and silently discarded by this:

```
} catch (Exception ex){}
```

You should NEVER catch and exceptions like that.

Comment: no i'm not getting the message but the file was added to the Context folder and it's empty

Comment: Well there's your answer then!  Replace the 'catch' with a catch for the specific exception or exceptions you are expecting ... and print out the stack trace.  That will tell you what the real problem is.

Comment: yes i Know  catching the exception this way is only for testing the ftp connection i dont intent to keep it that way

Comment: Your little temporary "put that off till later" had made your testing HARDER.  Hint: just don't do it ... at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try `outputStream.flush()` before you close it.

If that doesn't help you should check if any exceptions are thrown via `ex.printStackTrace()` in the try block. You often find the reason there (e.g. mising write permissions, connection error, ...).